# How to remove event from FullCalendar by clicking on Cross button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar

I wanted to create Full Calendar. FullCalendar is in modal when website opens in phone.
So I created Two div tag and hiding one tag depending on phone screen.

Once User select on full Calendar, Event will be added.

```
longPressDelay: 1,
selectAllow: function(selectInfo){
      return true;
 },
selectOverlap: function(event) {
    return true;
 },
select: function(info){
          var myid = makeid(8); // create random string
          calendar.addEvent({
            title: "test",
            start: info.startStr + "+09:00",
            end: info.endStr + "+09:00",
            editable: true,
            color: "#0000FF",
            id: myid,
          });
        },
```

Now To add, cross button on each event I used EventDidMount and I wanted to add cross button when event background color is `#0000FF`.

Once Cross button is added, I used onClick event to remove event.

```
eventDidMount: function(event){
          var v = event.event;
          if(event.backgroundColor === "#0000FF"){
            var myid = v.id;
            var v = event.el;
            let find = v.querySelector('.fc-event-main-frame');
            let myhtml = `<i class="fa fa-times float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>`;
            let mydiv = document.createElement('div');
            mydiv.className = 'close-event float-right';
            mydiv.innerHTML = myhtml;
            find.insertBefore(mydiv,find.firstChild);
            mydiv.onclick = function(){
              console.log("cross clicked");
              myevent = calendar.getEventById(myid);
              myevent.remove();
            }
          }
        },
```

Removing event is working perfectly on PC screen size but when I am switching to SP screen, Cross button is not getting removed.
So On PC screen size, `cross clicked` is in console on clicking cross but on SP screen size onClick event is not firing.
I can not see any problem in code, How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
    },
    defaultView: "month",
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: false,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

    select: function(start, end) {
      var title = prompt("Event Content:");
      var eventData;
      if (title) {
        eventData = {
          title: title,
          start: start,
          end: end,
          color: $("#colorPicker").val()
        };
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", eventData, true); // stick? = true
      }
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
    },

    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element
        .find(".fc-content")
        .prepend("<span class='closeBtn material-icons'>&#xe5cd;</span>");
      element.find(".closeBtn").on("click", function() {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents", event._id);
      });  
    },

    eventClick: function(calEvent) {
      var title = prompt("Edit Event Content:", calEvent.title);
      calEvent.title = title;
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
      
    },    
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrap {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.closeBtn {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>

<span><input type='color' id='colorPicker'></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: event render is changed to event render hooks in v5 documentation. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks